# Dashboard on Lightning page(Record detail page)

Tags: lightning, dashboard

I am trying to display a Dashboard on the record detail page, but I couldn't find the **Dashboard** standard component on the left-side pane. All I got is **Report Chart** component. So I decided to use this in the place of a dashboard.

But my main requirement is to provide a Filter at the top of the donut-chart for the end user(like on a Dashboard, we can provide one) to filter out the data based on his/her desire. I cannot get this with the Report Chart component. I am not sure if I can build a VF page that holds the Dashboard(with the Filters) and have it on the record detail page.

If not, do I need to implement this completely custom way? If at all I need to implement this in a Lightning component, can we embed a Dashboard with a filter in it? Are there any OOB components(something like `<aura:dashboard>` ) that can be used? Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed a regular Salesforce dashboard in a Lightning page or in a Visualforce page. About the best you can do is iframe the dashboard into a VF page, but if you want to pass to one of the dashboard filters, that won't work.

If you have Einstein Analytics, it is possible to [embed them on a record page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_embed_lightning.htm&type=5).

Another option would be to rebuild the dashboard using [VF charting.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_example.htm)

Comment: When I've tried using the **Wave Dashboard** component to get the embed dashboard, it is not listing any Dashboard in the drop-down. Thus my component is always "Invalid Component". What should I do to get my dashboard listed?

Comment: You can only embed dashboards built using Einstein Analytics which is a paid add-on. I suspect you built it using standard dashboards.

Comment: Oh yes, mine is standard dashboard. And I am trying all of these on my developer edition. With this, I can rule out the option of using **Wave Dashboard**. This is just ridiculous to build something that works on Classic but not on LEX.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't embed dashboards in classic record pages either.